# rails 5 Uninitialized constant RackDelegation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uninitialized-constant

I am working on a project which uses rails 5.0.0.rc2. Here is what I have done till now -

1. rails new DemoProject.
2. created gemset for ruby-2.3.1 and rails-5.0.0.rc2.
3. $ bundle install.
4. $ rails g model User name:string
5. Used devise gem.

   gem 'devise'

   $ rails generate devise:install

   $ rails generate devise User

Now, if I run rake:db migrate , I am receiving an error-

/home/swapnil/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@ruby-2.3.1-rails-5.0.0.rc2/gems/devise-3.5.10/lib/devise/failure_app.rb:9:in `': uninitialized constant ActionController::RackDelegation (NameError)

What is the reason behind it ? How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you're using Devise `3.5.10` which is not compatible with `Rails 5.0.0.rc2` . If using the latest Devise from RubyGems doesn't work for you, do this in your Gemfile . `gem 'devise', github: plataformatec/devise`

Checked my Rails 5.0.0.rc1 and my Devise version is 4.1.1 .

Comment: The reason is correct but solution did not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Devise 4.0 works with Rails 4.1 onwards.

So it was a problem with version of devise.

I upgraded it so that it is now compatible with rails 5.0.0.rc2.

> gem 'devise', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.1'

and run bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

This was the doorkeeper gem for me, needed to be bumped

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using this gem with Rails 5. Rails 5 already has rails-api merged in. So rails-api (this gem) and Rails 5 are not compatible you should just remove rails-api from the Gemfile.